# Gnome Extensions button not displaying extensions when pressed

Tags: gnome, 18.04, toshiba-satellite, gnome-shell-extension

I am learning to configure Ubuntu 18.04 to assist my low vision.
I am doing so on 2 gash 64-bit laptops before doing so on my main laptop.

On one, a Dell Vostro 1520, I have everything working to my satisfaction.

On the other, a Toshiba Satellite Pro L300-26R I am having a problem.

I have installed gnome extensions and added a few through the Firefox gnome extensions web site.  Although I have not been 100% methodical and consistent, I can work my way around to troubleshoot most problems but this one has me stumped.

I have dash-to-panel extension installed on both machines and aesthetically the desktop looks similar and I think I have checked both side-by-side to see what settings may differ - I can find nothing.

On the Toshiba when I press the extensions button on the dash/panel nothing happens.  Whereas on the Dell it lists all my current extensions and their setting.  I know I can use tweak - but I want the button to work from the dash-to-panel.  Could it really be a machine specific problem, or am I not just diligent and competent enough?

Answer (score 0):

In the end after a lot of fiddling around I ended up doing a fresh install of 18.04 on the offending Toshiba an doing step by step configuration from scratch, rebooting along the way and checking all was fine.

Dash-to-panel installation went fine as did adding the extensions button to the panel and the button worked.  It was at this point that I went to add some themes and icons and when I went to add 
Telinkrin theme here https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1215199/
and noticed this para for the first time

GTK+ 3.20 or later. Only standard (or Ubuntu) gnome-desktop is supported. Ready for Ubuntu 18.04
Disable gnome-extensions that reside on the headerbar because they mess up the headerbar-theming.

So that is what I did!  Now that there is no button there it cannot be pressed to see if it works ornot!!!  And for consistancy I removed it from the Vostro also haha.